# Ranking functions inside views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, ranking-functions

Is it reliable to use ranking functions inside views in sql server (2008 r2) and especially the

```
over (order by ...)
```

clause ?

It is known that the

```
order by
```

clause inside views in not a good approach, even if you specify the

```
top (100) percent
```

What about the

```
row_number() over(order by myColumn)
```

Sql server designer complains about it, but I cannot find any reliable info regarding this combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `row_number` works fine in views. The designer only handles limited syntax.

It does not guarantee any particular order for the `select` from the views though. For that you need an order by in the outer query.

One issue to be aware of is that, if you have a `partition by`, parameterised predicates on the partitioning column [won't be pushed down](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views) past that even though it would be more efficient to do so. And for that reason a parameterised inline table valued function may be preferred.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Good answer!